# Event sourcing - performance penalty?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

I am trying to convince people in my company that we should switch to event sourcing. Our software is a product that consist of many modules - like a module for wiki, blogs, documents, etc. I would like to use event sourcing also to allow easy collaboration on artifacts (like blogs), to have a history of changes, to minimize concurrent modification issues and so on.

There is also a feature of *staging* - where modules can be staged offline, so people can work on them; and then applied to online once when changes are finished.

The one of the reasons why no one wants to go this direction is the amount of events needed to be persisted. The events needed to be very granular, since of variety of actions users can do. But, there is no other operation on events then: 1) adding them 2) reading them from one point in time to the other. More over, we can have the concept of 'applied' events; some modules do not need to keep track of the full history, just the most recent ones.

So I wonder if there is any experience in how persisting events may influence the performance of the system?

Comment: IMHO these kind of discussions leads to nowhere (YMMV). To find out if event sourcing makes sense for your system, find an isolated use case where ES may be a solution, build a prototype, and see how it works.

Comment: recommended reading: **[How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)**

Comment: Hey, I do not want to have a discussion, I am looking for _experience_ here.

Answer (score 15):

I may be able to provide a bit of (biased) insight (that you shouldn't take at face value) since I recently had the pleasure to do a proof of concept in implementing eventsourcing for one of my companies products. Before this POC we had a "classic" system with a RDBMS in the bottom that did not save any events, the proof of concept was to replace the entire service layer with a CQRS architecture that used GetEventStore for eventsourcing and Raven as the read model.

In the end, there was no big performance change that our users could spot (sometimes faster, sometimes slower) compared to the classic RDBMS implementation. Why? Mainly because on the read side you are saving everything denormalized "ready for use" which makes querying really really fast and simple. Writing was also pretty fast even though we did the naive "read all events from a stream and apply them"-approach. But since we had done our due diligence in domain design we just had to read a single stream - and often enough a stream for a single aggregate did not have that many events so compared to the joining and grouping and stuff we did in the classic RDBMS way this turned out to not be much of a difference. And if we would have gotten enough events in a stream we could have used snapshots in order to not have to re-read every single event from a stream. But generally it's not necessary to perform such optimizations in advance - you'd be surprised how fast reading and applying events can be.

In the end though, this was slower (WAIT! Didn't I just say that it was about as fast earlier? Damn, you spotted my lies! :D) since we also went to a CQRS architecture where we had several servers communicating via messaging and thus also BASE consistency. Semantically compared to the classic RDBMS version this *was* slower since in order to have full consistency you'd have to wait until the event has gone through all the way to the read layer. However the users could rarely notice this added slowdown - and even when they did it was totally acceptable. And in many cases we realized that the users had no use for a full consistency model and we didn't need to wait for the event to go through the entire system. The users could just keep working anyway. This was kind of a "hard" realization that took a lot of time for our business people to accept, but it's the truth - consistency in a distributed system is a myth anyway, as soon as you show someone data on the screen it's most likely already old and out-of-date anyway.

In my experience, the main performance hit you take from eventsourcing is not from saving your data as a stream of events, that's pretty fast and if you get gigantic streams - start taking snapshots. The main performance hit you take is the one you choose yourself when you need to wait for events passing through the entire system.

Generally, I wouldn't say that "performance" is a good reason to not use eventsourcing.
Sadly, in the end, we did not choose to go in the eventsourcing direction at my company. Though this was not because of performance or any such reason - that was purely because we had too many people who got way too scared of throwing out the RDBMS. :(

Comment: Funny thing is, you don't really have to throw RDBMS out of the window. It's just fine to store events and read model in SQL. What you can throw away are unnecessary joins and horrible stored procedures. Too bad so few people want to appreciate the benefits :(

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it took a lot of effort to build a more complicated system that performed worse and with worse consistency than the existing one, and you're somehow disappointed it was scrapped? What am I missing? Honest question.

Comment: @kaqqao Honest answer, BASE isnt necessarily "worse" - it's merely "different", if its better or worse depends on your domain. And as long as the system is "fast enough" for what its doing additional performance is less valuable than other properties. What you get for this is total traceability of all your data in the system (which is a huge plus in certain domains), easier horizontal scalability, and in some cases a clearer modelling of your domain. Also we did not spend any time trying to optimize performance of this system, this was a "naive no-optimizations proof of concept" implementation

Comment: @kaqqao Everything in programming is about tradeoffs one way or another. Eventsourcing/CQRS is merely another way of trading a bunch of properties for another bunch of properties. If that tradeoff is good or not for your domain...that's something that only you can answer. However in many cases we tend to think that our domain is limited in a certain way (consistency model for example) just because we are used to that way and not because it's actually the truth. But in other cases, these limitations do exist. Exploring this is imho what makes programming hard - and fun :)